# Python, sqlalchemy and a fast way to get tables with schemas

Tags: python, reflection, sqlalchemy

I've been using sqlalchemy to do my rest implementation and now I want to get a list of tables from the database. I have tried these:

```
# first attempt
engine = create_engine(datasource.connection_string)
insp = reflection.Inspector.from_engine(engine)
tables = insp.get_table_names()
view = insp.get_view_names()

# second attempt
meta = MetaData()
meta.reflect(bind=engine, views=True)
```

While they both work perfectly fine they both have their downsides.

1. The first does not give me the schema but only the object name
2. The second gives me the world but runs dog slow...
3. For both there is no filtering

Using a sql-statement is not an option since I need it to be somewhat cross-db.

Is there a way to quickly load the objects including schema? Filtering is of less importance since I can do that on the list of objects fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

`get_table_names()` and `meta.reflect()` only load tables from one schema at a time.  If an explicit schema name is not given, the "default" schema is assumed, which is the schema that your database connection automatically selects when you connect; this is configured on the database side in conjunction with the user account used to connect.

if you want to see the name of this schema, use the "default_schema_name" property:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import create_engine, inspect
>>> e = create_engine("postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost/test")
>>> insp = inspect(e)
>>> insp.default_schema_name
u'public'
```